# error when running selenium/standalone-chrome docker and java client to to use the remoteWebDriver

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, selenium

I am trying to run selenium inside docker, 
I have a spring bean that looks like this

```
    @Bean
    public WebDriver chromeDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");
//        URL url = new URL("http://172.17.0.2:4444/wd/hub");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("headless");
        options.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"chrome");
        RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, options);
        return remoteWebDriver;
    }
```

I have tried both options withe the IP and localhost, I am starting my docker selenium image like this

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
```

When I run my application on docker I keep getting

```
Factory method 'chromeDriver' threw exception; nested exception is org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
or
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /172.17.0.2:4444
```

If I run my spring application locally with this set up it works but it won't work when I run both the applications on docker. I know I am doing something silly just couldn't figure out what

Comment: Instead of using localhost please. use IP address. I am a docker toolbox user so I have different IP for docker it starts with 192.168.x.x. So  I believe that you must check for the same . In order to verify whether everything is alright, you can hit the URL http://<ip>:<port> (e.g http://192.168.9.0:4444 ) in the web browser. If it is accessible then everything is okay otherwise it is not working.

Comment: yeah, I have tried to do that i used this command to get the IP
 "docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' [imageId]" , which gave me 172.17.0.2:4444 but that is not working either.

Comment: Are you able to ping your docker ip from host?

Comment: I can reach "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub" but not with the IP address

Comment: So in that case could you use 127.0..0.1 instead of localhost.